# How to activate Automatic Logging in Terminator?

Tags: logging, terminator

I'm using [Terminator (terminal emulator)](https://code.google.com/p/jessies/wiki/Terminator). I had to capture all the terminal logs and hence I set infinite-scroll ON but ultimately I found that actually it's not scrollable more than few hundred lines. [The webpage](https://code.google.com/p/jessies/wiki/Terminator) says that there is a feature called "**Automatic Logging**" but it says no more words about it i.e how to enable it and where to search for the log (location of the log file). Please help me for the same.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enable the logger:

1. Right click on terminator screen
2. Click Preferences
3. Go to Plugins tab
4. Enable Logger
5. Click close

Start logging:

1. Right Click on terminator screen again
2. Click start logger

Comment: Is there an easy way to have it start automatically and with specified naming convention on the output log file? - at least the command-line way to start logging so I can add to my bashrc

Comment: Don't forget to right click and stop logging when done too, or else you lose everything in the log if you just close the terminal window when done. [I mention that in my anwser here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62493626/4561887)

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-Click on the screen in Terminator --> "Preferences" --> click the "Plugins" tab --> check the box for "Logger" --> click "Close".

   [image]
2. **Right-Click on the screen --> "Start Logger"**:

   [image]

   It will now bring up a window to ask you where you want to save your log file. Save it wherever you want. Ex: **~/logs/terminator.log**.
3. Now, use the terminal as normal, and pretty much everything, including both commands and output (but not sub-shells and things I believe), will be logged. See here for the minimal official documentation on the logger: https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html#logger.
4. When done, **Right-Click on the screen --> "Stop Logger"**.

   (***Caution: don't lose your log!:*** if you just close the terminal window instead of manually stopping the logger via the menu, you will lose almost all, or all, of the logging content. This is frustrating and is a bug at the time of writing).

### References:

1. [How to activate Automatic Logging in Terminator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472973/how-to-activate-automatic-logging-in-terminator/38187645#38187645)
2. Terminator official documentation (accessed via Right-Click --> Preferences --> Help): https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

   1. Official Logger documentation: https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html#logger

      [image]